# Docker Compose for MysQL and Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have an Spring boot application that i'm enabling to work with Docker. As per the practice, i have created a two docker container and connected them via network. My docker compose is as below

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql-docker-container:
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      - reminder
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=quartz
      - MYSQL_USER=quartz
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=quartz
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  reminder-docker-container:
    image: reminder-scheduler
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-docker-container:3306/quartz?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false 
      - spring.sql.init.mode=always
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container
    networks:
      - reminder
networks:
  reminder:
```

once I run, mysql container works fine but the application container throws error

```
reminder-docker-container_1  | 2021-08-24 19:19:13,535 [ 594evel] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
reminder-docker-container_1  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
reminder-docker-container_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
```

Please help...

Comment: What about `spring.datasource.username` & `spring.datasource.password` I dont see configuration parameters in `reminder-docker-container`

Comment: Try SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL and SPRING_SQL_INIT_MODE in the environment.

Comment: The spring.datsource.username and password are defined in the application properties file.

Comment: I have changes the variables as Suggested to SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL and SPRING_SQL_INIT_MODE.  I still get the same error. 2021-08-25 16:10:15,873 [ 594evel] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
reminder-docker-container_1  | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up